# What $x \in IN$ mean?

Tags: notation, real-numbers, natural-numbers

Here is the part of the math problem I'm trying to understand.

$A=\{x|x \in IN: x^3>25 \,\, and \,\, x^4<264\}$

I know $N$ is used to denote **Natural Numbers**. But I'm unfamiliar with $IN$. I have done Google searches, but I didn't find anything helpful.

This part of the math problem is from a printed textbook. So I was wondering whether this were a typo.

Comment: I don't think it's standard notation. Could be maybe just some typing or font error, probably they mean $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Is it definitely an I rather than a Roman $1$? I have seen similar but not exact notation used elsewhere that is used to denote $\mathbb{N}$ starting at $1$, i.e., $\mathbb{1N}=\{1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$, or sometimes $\mathbb{N}_1$.

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo.

Comment: They probably wanted to write $\text{I}\!\text{N}$, i.e., merging an $I$ and an $N$ to produce a notation for the set of natural numbers. $\mathbb N$ is better though.

Comment: I think we all agree that $\mathbb{N}$ is meant.

Comment: @EverywhereDense Roman $1$ and I look similar. There isn't any space between the letters. Together it looks like $IN$.

Comment: I have seen several people think that it reads $IN$ when it's supposed to be $\mathbb N$.

Comment: What @Gary said. In the Olden Days, to write $\mathbb N$ on a typewriter (the ancient technology of the time) one would type `I`, then backspace a bit, and type `N`.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to look at this. Your valuable comments have helped me to reach a conclusion about this.